# Can my iphone app name be different from my bundle identifier?

Tags: iphone

My application name is different from my bundle identifier. I am using another language (arabic) for my application. In xcode, I had named my application in arabic, but in my bundle identifier, the name is in english... which one will actually appear in the app store? I noticed that xcode won't let me use the language in my identifier.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  This happens all the time on the app store (where the iTunes name is much longer than the bundle name).  Just make sure it properly represents your application.

The one that appears in the App Store is the one you set up in iTunes Connect, while the one that appears under the icon on the device is the one you enter in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can change it by changing the product name under the build settings. When you change the bundle identifier, It will only show the bundle identifier name on ipad/iphone. But the product name on app store will be the name that is there in product Name under build section. Hence, to change the name on app store change the product name.

Comment: but then the problem here is that if the product name is in non-ascii characters.. and the bundle identifier relies on the product name.. then you won't be able to create an app identifier in the developer portal.. as it doesn't accept non-ascii characters in the app id.. suggestions?

Comment: @abbood I think using non ascii character in the app id id not acceptable as Apple has put up its own restriction on that

Answer (score 2):

in the info.plist file, add the property Bundle display name and put the value to whatever name you want to appear on the user's iDevice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can be. You can change the name by editing it under "product name" under the build settings tab.